# Prove/disprove statement about functions with special properties

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $H:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following:

1. $H\geq0$ everywhere and $H(x)=0\iff x=0$;
2. $H\in\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^{2n}\smallsetminus\{0\})$;
3. $H$ is positively homogeneous of degree 2 (i.e. for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}\smallsetminus\{0\},\lambda>0$ we have $H(\lambda x)=\lambda^2H(x)$);
4. The Hessian of $H$ is everywhere positive definite, except at most in the origin;
5. The level sets of $H$ are all compact.

I know the gradient $\nabla H$ is therefore injective. But can it be proven (in general, for in some cases it is of course possible) it is surjective as well? And if not, can you provide a counterexample? Does this statement's truth depend on the dimension (i.e. on $n$)?

Comment: Certainly there exist cases for all $n$ where you can prove surjectivity of gradient. Consider $H(x_1, \ldots, x_{2n}) = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_{2n}^2$

Comment: Naturally in some cases one can prove it, but I'm asking for either a general proof or a counterexample, as the added bracketed sentence (I hope) makes clear.

Comment: PS I just realized I have a missing property: the level sets must be compact. Otherwise $e^{-x-y}$ is an easy counterexample, since its gradient is $-(1,1)e^{-x-y}$, which is evidently not surjective. But its level sets are lines, decidedly not compact.

Comment: I don't think $e^{-x-y}$ is a counterexample, as it doesn't satisfy condition $(3)$. You're fine. The level sets must be compact by homogeneity deg. $2$.

Comment: Ah whoops you're right :). Better make it explicit anyway.

Comment: I think I have it. $H$ must be of the form $H(x)=\sum a_ix_i^2$. So the gradient is $\nabla H(x)=2(a_1x_1,\dotsc,a_{2n}x_{2n})$, which is obviously surjective. Right?

Comment: No, I could still have a $x_ix_j$ term. So $H(x)=\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}x_ix_j$.

Comment: Which has gradient $\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}x_ie_j$, $e_j$ being the $j$-th coordinate vector. Is this surjective in general?

Comment: That is correct. More intuitively speaking, such an $H$ must be convex, so the intersection through $\mathbf{0}$ of any plane orthogonal to the $2n$ coordinate axes (in $2n+1$-space) with the graph must look like a parabola.

Comment: Let us move to commenting on my answer below. And those coefficients might depend on what half-line I lie on with my $x$, because the level sets may not be symmetric w.r.t the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, $H(x)$ must be:

$$H(x)=\sum_{i\leq j}a_{ij}x_ix_j,$$

for $a_{ij}$ real coefficients, by positive homogeneity. Then its Hessian is precisely the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, which is therefore invertible. But the gradient is:

$$\nabla H(x)=x\cdot A\cdot(e_1,\dotsc,e_{2n})^T,$$

so the equation $\nabla H(x)=y$ as solution $x=y\cdot A^{-1}$.

Actually, having only positive homogeneity those coefficients may depend on the half-line where $x$ lies. Still, the above should yield surjectivity.

**Update**

Here is how the comments continue in chat: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4N2O.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKDYO.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSAsL.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLUyp.png), [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Ndu.png).

Comment: I don't think it's instructive to construct a gradient. You don't need to assume a certain structure of $H$ to solve this problem. Reduce to the one-variable case. Any plane cutting the graph orthogonally through $0$ in $2n+1$-space will be a parabola - it must, by $(3)$. So, you are done. The gradient of the function along a given parabola will be surjective.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure why you say you know the gradient is injective. Nothing guarantees it.

Comment: The positive definiteness of the Hessian does.

Comment: Consider again $H = $ sum of squares of components. The gradient of this function is not one-to-one at all.

Comment: The gradient of that function is 2 times the identity, isn't it? So how is it not one-to-one? Besides, that p.d. Hessian guarantees injective gradient is shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1372726/135592).

Comment: You misinterpret that question, it asks about the nabla operator, not the gradient of a function itself. The gradient of $H$ is a map $\nabla H : \mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the level sets of the example of sums of squares of components.

Comment: Perhaps we have a terminological issue: I define $\nabla H(x)=(\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_1}(x),\dotsc,\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{2n}}(x))$, and I'm talking about _this map_, which clearly has values in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, and not real values. And that is what I call _gradient of $H$_. Now, that question is talking about this, isn't it? What is your definition of gradient? The map taking $y$ to the dot product of my vector $\nabla H(x)$ and $y$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31954/discussion-between-evan-coleman-and-mickg).